# Java - Manually reading bytes in bitmap file

Tags: java, bitmap

I have seen how to read each individual pixel from an image with `BufferedImage`. However, the environment I am using has no `java.nio`, no `javax.imageio`, etc. All it really has is `DataInputStream`.

I am using http://www.daubnet.com/en/file-format-bmp for the bitmap format.
I tested reading just the width and height on a test 6x6 image, and it did not return the correct numbers.

How can I manually read the file byte by byte and retrieve the width and height and color of each pixel?

I have seen `ByteBuffer` used for byte manipulation; keep in mind that I cannot use that class as it is not supported in the environment I am working with.

Comment: `java.io` has all the classes you need to read files. You'll need to either write the code to decode a BMP file or find a library that does it for you, though.

Comment: @vanza Yes, I'm wondering how to decode the BMP file. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: I recommend having a look at an existing library like [BMP I/O library](http://thorntonzone.com/manuals/Compression/Fax,%20IBM%20MMR/MMSC/mmsc/uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/bmp/) for reference. Especially the following class might help you on your way: [BMPImageReader](http://thorntonzone.com/manuals/Compression/Fax,%20IBM%20MMR/MMSC/mmsc/uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/bmp/BMPImageReader.java).

Comment: The image size is 6x6, so there would be 2-byte 0-padding in each of the 6 rows of pixels. Did you handle that?

Comment: @Balder Now it works, but before your link was broken. Anyways, I just googled for a bmp io library and figured it out. I must use little endian though.